# How to set speed limit per IP in IP range in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, openvpn, tc

**What I want:**
I've setup a openvpn-server and want the clients in range of 10.8.0.0/21 limit their speed to **10mbit for each IP** as a total limit of 100mbit.

```
wan interface     : eth0
openvpn interface : tun0
clients ip range  : 10.8.0.0/21
```

**What I have done:**
I've setup the tc filter with below config.

tc filter rules :

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 10
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:10 htb rate 100mbit
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.8.0.0/21 flowid 1:20
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:20 classid 1:30 htb rate 10mbit
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 10
```

**What is the problem:**
When **two client connect** to server their speed will divide into **two 5mbit** (on usage).
it seems the total range of 10.8.0.0/21 get a speed limit of 10mbit and not a limit per IP.